# Is there any key-value container which stores their elements without any reordering

Tags: c++

Is there any key-value container which stores their elements without any reordering unlike std::map and std::unordered_map? I don't want to use std::vector btw. Maybe boost?

Comment: Do you mean you want to iterate over the container in its insertion order?

Comment: `I don't want to use std::vector` - then you're gonna suffer badly. `std::vector<std::pair<Key, Value>>` would do the job pretty well.

Comment: Yes, I want to iterate it in its insertion order

Comment: Based on your stated requirements, `vector` is the right answer. If you insist you can't use that (why?) then `deque` is probably the next closest fit. If you want access both via key *and* in insertion order, then you probably want a combination, such as inserting the item itself into a vector, and a key and pointer to the item into some sort of map (or vice versa). The answer suggesting Boost multiIndex is undoubtedly assuming that's what you want (and if it is, then it's quite a good answer).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, using [Boost.MultiIndex](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0b1/libs/multi_index/doc/index.html); specifically, you want to combine [`sequenced`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0b1/libs/multi_index/doc/reference/seq_indices.html) with an [`ordered`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0b1/libs/multi_index/doc/reference/ord_indices.html) (or possibly [`hashed`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0b1/libs/multi_index/doc/reference/hash_indices.html)) index.

There's [an example](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0b1/libs/multi_index/example/sequenced.cpp) combining `sequenced` with `ordered_non_unique`; it should be possible to adapt it to your use case.

Comment: What's the advantage over `std::vector`?

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf you get O(log n) (ordered) or O(1) (hashed) lookup by key, without having to maintain a separate index manually.